# how can i use TModel and custom model both or can substitute?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

I am using `asp.net` mvc.
in View,

```
@using System.Data

<table>
   <thead>
       <tr>
           @foreach (DataColumn col in Model.Columns)
           {
               <th>@col.ColumnName</th>
       }
   </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
           @foreach (DataRow row in Model.Rows)
           {
              <tr>
               @foreach (DataColumn col in Model.Columns)
                  {
                   <td>@row[col.ColumnName]</td>
                  }
            </tr>
          }
      </tbody>
```

like using `Model.Columns`, `Model.Rows`

and I want use myModel

So write code on top

```
@model myprojectname.Models.ItemViewModel
```

then I got an error

> Model.Columns points to ItemViewModel (do not intent)

but I want to use ItemViewModel

My Question is how can I use myViewModel

doesn't affect

```
@foreach (DataColumn col in Model.Columns)
```

this part

if not, then I will hardcode on (to add part) or (this foreach part)

---

add

ItemViewModels.cs

```
public class ItemViewModel
{
    public string item_id { get; set; }
    //public string item_type { get; set; }
    public string item_name { get; set; }
    public string user_name { get; set; }
    public string location { get; set; }
    public string model_name { get; set; }
    public string manufacturer { get; set; }
    public string serial_number { get; set; }
    public string serial_number2 { get; set; }
    public string specifications { get; set; }
    public DateTime date_of_manufacture { get; set; }
    public DateTime date_of_purchase { get; set; }
    public string note { get; set; }
    public int state { get; set; }
    public ItemTypes item_type { get; set; }

    public ItemState item_state { get; set; }

    public enum ItemTypes
    {
        PC_데스크탑 = 'D',
        네트워크장비 = 'Z',
        노트북 = 'N',
        맥북 = 'N',
        모니터 = 'M',
        모바일 = 'P',
        백업장비 = 'S',
        타블렛 = 'W',
        태블릿 = 'T',
        키보드 = 'K',
        마우스 = 'U'
    }

    public enum ItemState
    {
        사용 = 1,
        미사용 = 2,
        AS대기 = 3,
        AS중 = 4,
        폐기예정 = 5,
        폐기완료 = 6
    }
}
```

and Controller.cs

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
   ......
using (DataSet dsResult = callWcfService.fnGetQuery(sXmlParam))
{
  return View(dsResult.Tables[0]);
} 
 }
```

i want to make like this on view

```
@Html.EnumDropDownListFor(model => model.item_type, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

so i need to ref modelView

and

```
@foreach (DataColumn col in Model.Columns)
```

mouseover on Model

vs show info
[dynamic WebvViewPage.Model {get;} 
get Model property connected ViewDataDictionary object]

but after adding
    @model myprojectname.Models.ItemViewModel

it changes [ItemViewModel has no definition on Rows, Columns]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you'd like to use both DataTable and your ViewModel, you can create a new ViewModel that includes properties for DataTable and your ViewModel used. To make your code neater, I don't recommend you to do this. For common situation, one ViewModel is enough to serve a View, you don't have to compose your models into a new model. So if all your data is only for display purpose, maybe you can consider to add more properties to your model, then assign all the data of DataTable to those properties.

Comment: thanks your answer, i should try to pass itemviewmodel with dsResult.Tables[0] in controller. and if i still fail, i modify code quite a lot.